C#, sorting coordinates into continuous line
I have the following coordinates for a line OR potentially non-convex polygon:

Rules:

each coordinate is at MOST 1 x or 1 y distance away
the coordinates WILL form a line with two end coordinates OR a fully connected loop (a polygon)

These coordinates come in a potentially random order. Ex:
5,3
3,4
4,4
6,4
2,5
6,5
2,6
5,6
3,6

I would like these sorted into a list, starting at one end, ending at another. It doesn't matter if it's clockwise or counterclockwise
Ex:
3,7
2,6
2,5
3,4
4,4
5,3
6,4
6,5
5,6
I could start at a random point, then search for an adjacent neighbour (since I know they're at most 1,1 away), but this solution is O(n2) and computationally complex
I know for a concave polygon, you can sort by using angle from atan from an internal point, but if the lines connect it may form a convex polygon.

I think you are looking for the convex hull algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-algorithm/

Since each point is at most 1 away, you can find the neighbor in constant time but just trying all the possible steps. With a hash set, this is O(n) overall.

This is a Dijkstra problem solving for shortest path.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#:~:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20the%20shortest,its%20constituent%20edges%20is%20minimized.  You need to calculate the distance between point using sqrt(x^2 + y^2) as the distance between points.

@jdweng, I do not understand how you think this is dijkstra as dijkstra goes for the shortest path beween a set of points. I do not even know if DeeCeptor is looking for the convex-hull as it would exclude 3,4.

@Aldert : Would Dijkstra solve the OP issue using shortest path and go through all the points?
